# TDebugInterfacedObject in which unit?

Tags: delphi

I need to find TDebugInterfacedObject defined in which unit ? Do you know where it is ?

Comment: Are you sure about the name of the class? maybe you are looking for `TInterfacedObject`

Comment: It is not part of any Delphi distribution since Delphi 7. Perhaps some 3rd party code you have used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking at [some code Deborah Pate submitted](https://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.oleautomation/msg/a57d99e0e52c78ce) to the Borland newsgroups back in 2003 in the thread "Sinking events in EmbeddedWB or WebBrowser":

```
type
  TEventObject = class(TDebugInterfacedObject, IDispatch)
  private
    FOnEvent: TProcedure;
...
```

Immediately after posting that code, [she posted again](https://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.oleautomation/msg/ab5d8e558be4fe33) to correct her mistake:

> Oops - take the 'Debug' out of there. :)

Just use `TInterfacedObject`. You're welcome to write your own `TDebugInterfacedObject` for your own debugging purposes if you want to. That's probably what Pate had done, but she forgot to clean up that part of the code before posting it publicly.

Answer (score 3):

As far I know the `TDebugInterfacedObject` class is not part of the RTL, maybe you are looking for [TInterfacedObject](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TInterfacedObject) which is declarated in the System unit or another option is that class is in some Third-party library.